# Upload batch Job XML in Control-M enterprise manager automatically through linux script

Tags: xml, linux, batch-file, control-m, service-control-manager

Please suggest how to Upload batch Job XML in Control-M enterprise manager automatically through Linux script.
Everyday I have to upload this XML through Control-M Desktop and then it gets reflected in Control-M enterprise manager for the jobs to run.

Please suggest how to apply automation in this process, so that I can upload this XML in Control-M enterprise manager through a Linux script everyday on triggering the script. 
This will reduce manual effort.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Control-M, and click on the help icon. Then do a search for "emdef". This is a utility that comes packaged with Control-M, and can be used to export and update job definitions. For instance,

```
 emdef.exe exportdefjob -pf password.prop -s servername -arg args.txt -out jobDefinitions.txt
```

The documentation in Control-M will help you with additional flags and examples.